# Kubernetes: Delete secret from pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

I have pod running my application. The pod also contains my secret. The secret mapped to `/secret/mysecret.json`. I connecting to my pod with ssh and try to remove the secret from this pod instance:

```
rm /secret/mysecret.json
```

I getting the Error:

```
rm: cannot remove 'mysecret.json': Read-only file system
```

According to [this article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/), I tried to changed the `readOnly` settings to `False`. No success.

Also tried to unmount it, got errors:

```
$ umount /secret/mysecret.json
  umount: /app/secrets/app-specific: must be superuser to unmount
```

How I can delete secret from a pod?

Answer (score 14):

The way you should handle this the kubernetes way is:

```
kubectl delete secret <<secret name goes here>>
```

Comment: This will remove the secret from the cluster. I'm looking to remove the secret file from the pod instance (after loading and reading the secret).

Comment: There is no concept of deleting or unmounting an artifact once deployed (and yet allow them to be running or hosted) on k8s cluster. Why is this even a requirement?

Comment: After reading the certificate, I dont want to leaved them there. Just want to destroy them. It's security issue.

Comment: You must understand that pods come and go, just like any other feature of k8s, in the event if pods go away, how will you ensure that the secrets are preserved when they instantiate again!

Comment: @RaunakJhawar You did not get the point.
Ability to delete secrets can seriously increase security of containerized application to store secrets only in memory of application, not in the environments or files since they do need after container start.

Answer (score 4):

You can not delete secret from pod as it is mapped as volume. Even if you managed to delete, it will be recreated. So if you want to remove secret from pod,  change pod spec and delete that secret conf from spec itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sounds wired that those files cannot be deleted without removing them form the YAML file. So, why the `readOnly` option mentioned there?

Comment: readOnly option used to make that not changeable. You can not edit that secret once created. It has nothing to do with delete Or remove.

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete certificate first

`kubectl delete certificates <<secret name goes here>>`, then delete secret

`kubectl delete secret <<secret name goes here>>`.